Safe for an object to return a lock on itself?
Is this code correct / advisable style? That is, is the lock being returned guaranteed to keep the mutex locked through the process of being returned , as opposed to say unlocking then re-locking (or even unlocking and staying unlocked). I am worried about the action of the destructor of the return value.
#include <mutex>

struct BigObject
{
    auto get_lock()
    {
         return std::scoped_lock<std::mutex>(m_mutex);
    }
private:
    std::mutex m_mutex;
};

BigObject big;

int main()
{
    auto lock = big.get_lock();
    
    // ...
}

Assume context of some larger program with concurrent access to the global big.
The "normal" style would be for the caller to declare and initialize the lock, but here we encapsulate the mutex and have the caller call a function.  So the object can only be locked via this entry point.
Bonus question - would std::lock_guard instead of std::scoped_lock also be correct?

While not strictly necessary in this case, unique_lock<> would be a better match in my opinion since it has a move-constructor. That saves you the trouble of redesigning the API if copy-elision ever doesn't work

I would highly recommend marking get_lock() as [[nodiscard]]. Otherwise you run the risk of the caller accidentally dropping the lock if they forget assigning it to a local variable.

I dont understand " So the object can only be locked via this entry point." what prevents a user from not calling get_lock but use their own lock, or no lock at all?

In my project, one of the devs uses a pattern passing in a function<void(BigObject&)> (which is typically a lambda) to an execute method.  The execute method obtains the lock and then calls the fn(*this).  I'm not sure I like this pattern, and if it isn't a "leaf" function call there's a danger of deadlock.  (The dev that is using it is only used for "leaf" calls, for unit testing.  So for that special case, it works.  For general purpose use, not as much.)

No never return locks (they should stay inside a scope, it is not called scoped_lock for nothing ). Making an object threadsafe is something that is should handle internally, OR you should handle at a more global level.

So the real question is WHAT are you trying to do.

@PepijnKramer if each function locks the object, then the caller can't call several functions on the object efficiently and atomically.

@M.M I totally agree, but then the object itself should be lock free and the synchronization/multithreading issues be solved completely outside the object and the locking becomes an architecture design issue. (scattering locks around only complicates stuff)

@PepijnKramer is lock-free always possible? In the "real code" of this case, I'm storing things in a std::map and also want to atomically know the size of the map before/after the store (i.e. two concurrent callers shouldn't both get the same size back)

@MM No ofcourse not, but that's also not what I wanted to say. Locking is something you really have to design for (and exporting locks from classes is in my experience just extra complication not a tennable solution). Or you lock the code that calls your class, or you have locks inside the class, but you shouldn't pass locks accross boundaries of classes.


is the lock being returned guaranteed to keep the mutex locked through the process of being returned , as opposed to say unlocking then re-locking (or even unlocking and staying unlocked). I am worried about the action of the destructor of the return value.

Yes, it will keep the lock and there is no destructor involved. The std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> is created directly in the receiving variable due to return value optimization (RVO). It's guaranteed since C++17, and you are using at least C++17.

would std::lock_guard instead of std::scoped_lock also be correct?

Yes, since C++17. In C++14 and earlier, it wouldn't even compile.

An alternative could be to make your object lockable:
struct BigObject {
    void lock() { m_mutex.lock(); }
    void unlock() { m_mutex.unlock(); }
    bool try_lock() { return m_mutex.try_lock(); }

private:
    std::mutex m_mutex;
};

It would now be locked just any other mutex and the user could use whatever lock that is needed, be it a unique_lock or scoped_lock, which would be hard with your current approach:
std::scoped_lock lock(big, another_lockable);



Is this code correct / advisable style?

I'd recommend making BigObject itself Lockable (or even just BasicLockable, without try_lock, if multiple object locking should be discouraged).
struct BigObject
{
    void lock()
    {
         m_mutex.lock();
    }
    
    void unlock()
    {
         m_mutex.unlock();
    }

    bool try_lock() {
         return m_mutex.try_lock();
    }

private:
    std::mutex m_mutex;
};

This allows plugging BigObject itself into std::unique_lock, std::scoped_lock, and so forth. Which means the user of the object has finer grained control over the sort of RAII guard and locking semantics they need.
The added bonus is that if you wish to extend locking support to shared locks (or even just add try_lock), it shouldn't disturb existing users of BigObject, since their RAII guards are still valid for the semantics they use.

Thanks, your answer was good, although I accepted another answer as it also addressed my question of whether the original code was valid; as well as proposing the better alternative.


Is this code correct / advisable style?

To offer another alternative, consider creating a proxy object that holds the lock. Give the proxy object all methods that require locked access to the parent object. Prevent access without the proxy by making attributes private.
This way, you cannot forget to acquire the lock. Something like this:
#include <mutex>

class BigObject
{
public:
    class Locked
    {
        BigObject* parent;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock;
    public:
        explicit Locked(BigObject* parent)
        : parent(parent), lock(parent->m_mutex)
        {}
        // inline proxy
        void set_val(int x)
        { parent->m_val = x; }
    };
    auto lock()
    { return Locked{this}; }
private:
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    int m_val;
};

BigObject big;

int main()
{
    auto locked = big.lock();
    locked.set_val(12);
    // or as one line: big.lock().set_val(12)
}

